# Should we have validator for our associations in the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am pretty new to rails and some concepts are still confusing, so I was writing a model and I defined my foreign keys, then I also defined my validators some easy ones like some fields shouldn't be blank.
For example:

```
class KeyPerformanceInd < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :name, :organization_id, :target

  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  belongs_to :organization
  has_many  :key_performance_intervals, :foreign_key => 'kpi_id'

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :target, presence: true
  validates :organization_id, presence: true

end
```

Then the question that came to mind was that hmm should I also write some sore of validator in this model that makes sure the key in the other table that we are using as foreign_key also exists and is valid or something in that effect?
Or is it something we do in our RSpec tests? and not in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally write rspec model test for associations, in this case

```
Describe KeyPerformanceInd do
  it {should belong_to(:key_performance_interval)}
end
```

Comment: thanks, so not needed to also have something in the model for it.

Comment: yep, you have to have belongs_to :key_performance_interval in the model